# Contrasting the microcanonical ensemble with the general approach to thermal equilibrium

Tags: statistical-mechanics

For those wondering precisely what I am referencing throughout, I am contrasting the discussion in Reif Chapter 3.4 (general thermal equilibrium) with Chapter 6.2 (microcanonical ensemble).

In the most general approach to thermal equilibrium (let us consider subsystems A and A' in which no external parameters for either change, so that A and A' only interact thermally), one finds the thermal equilibrium by finding respective energies $E$ and $E'$ of each (where $E+E'=E_o$, the energy of the isolated composite system) such that the temperatures of the two subsystems are equal. For subsystems with relatively many degrees of freedom, it is then a simple matter to show that there is an overwhelming probability that energies are distributed at thermal equilibrium according to the energies found in equating temperatures in the aforementioned steps.

Now fix A' as a heat reservoir. From the general formalism of the canonical ensemble, given some system A I can usually fix a temperature $T$ for A' (in particular, one that is large enough) which is such that many microstates of A have non-negligible probabilities associated with them.

The two previous paragraphs seem to be at odds. In particular, I wonder:

1. If I am at a high enough temperature, then how is it in general that the smaller system A will have an energy (or region of energies) which gives a number of states function $\Omega(E)$ with "sufficient derivative" $\partial \Omega(E)/\partial E$ to achieve the fixed temperature of the heat reservoir?
2. Supposing that such a temperature is "achievable" by A, the following still seems to be at odds between the two paragraphs. The first paragraph seems to indicate that there will be one state of A which is overwhelmingly probable, and yet the second paragraph seems to suggest that many states of A can be non-negligibly probable. Here I think the resolution is simply that the energies $E$ of A are small compared to those $E'$ of A', so "fluctuations" to different A energies are within the tight range dictated by the first paragraph.

Hopefully someone can explain (1) to me and make my comment in (2) (if correct) more precise.

Comment: (1) Could you rephrase your first question as something like: "suppose you had a system where all microstates had energy less than $E$, coupled to a thermal bath with $kT\gg E$, then would the system reach equilibrium"? (2) The answer to your second question is that the distribution is sharply peaked around a given *macrostate*, but there can be many microstates consistent with a given macrostate. So there can be many microstates all with an equal probability, which all have the same average energy and volume (for example).

Comment: @Andrew Regarding (1), I’m not sure I follow if that’s exactly a rephrasing, but it may well be. Regarding (2), I agree that the macro state in which system A has energy E may well correspond to very many micro states. But this is not what I’m asking about. We can see that it’s possible for A to be in different energy macro states ($E_1, E_2,…$), but where the probability of fluctuations is ostensibly much larger than from general thermal equilibrium arguments. My thought it this that these different energies of A are small on the scale of the composite system, so there is no paradox.

Comment: I'm confused as to exactly what you are asking with (1). Let $\Omega(E_0)$ be the number of states of the whole system, $\Omega_A(E_A)$ be the number of states of system $A$ at energy $E_A$, and $\Omega_{A'}(E_0-E_A)$ be the number of states of system $A'$ at energy $E_0-E_A$. Given $E_0$, we want to choose $E_A$ to maximize $\Omega(E_0)=\Omega_A(E_A) \Omega_{A'}(E_0-E_A)$. Since $0<E_A<E_0$, we're always going to be able to find a maximum. (Maybe there's a weird pathological case where $E_A$ can be arbitrarily negative and $\Omega(E_0)$ doesn't have a maximum, but this seems unphysical)

Comment: Generally you expect $\Omega_A(E_A)$ to increase with $E_A$ and $\Omega_{A'}(E_0-E_A)$ to decrease with $E_A$, so their product has a peak. There are weird cases with negative temperatures where this doesn't happen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature

Comment: @Andrew To clarify, I mean the following. If the small system A is in equilibrium with the temperature $\beta '$ of system A', then $\beta = \partial \Omega(E)/\partial E = \beta '$ at equilibrium. Are you saying that no matter the $\beta '$, A will always have some energy level where it's derivative is large enough to match that of A'? What of a spin system, where there is certainly some maximum given the finite number of states available?

Comment: Also, did my answer to (2) make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136758/discussion-between-andrew-and-ee18).

Comment: As far as I know, since the function $\Omega(E)$ wildly changes with $E$, its logarithm $\ln \Omega(E)$ is used. Therefore the most probable state is given by the one satisfying $\partial_E \ln \Omega_1(E)=\partial_E \ln \Omega_2(E)$ which gives $\partial_E \Omega_1(E)/\Omega_1(E)=\partial_E \Omega_2(E)/\Omega_2(E)$ therefore both sides are somehow normalized to their system size.